# BOLT CMS - disable search for certain field

Tags: php, bolt-cms

Is there any possibility to disable search for certain field? Searchweight set to 0 for 'button' still shows search result based on his content. My code in contenttypes.yml:

```
foo:
show_in_menu: Bar
name: Foo Bar
taxonomy: [sorters]
fields:
    title:
        type: text
        group: General
    lead:
        type: textarea
        group: General
    url:
        type: text
        group: General
    button:
        type: text
        required: true
        pattern: ^.{1,15}$
        searchweight: 0
        group: Button
        label: Text on button
        postfix: Required, max 15 characters.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add in your contenttype area: `searchable: false`

Comment: It works for whole contenttype, not for specified field ('button' in this example)